# create user choice form and store that value into database

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

I want create a custom form and that value into database using civicrm.

How can I create this using civiCRM and drupal.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create custom field for a contact and then include the custom field on drupal webform.

Below are the documentation to

- [Create custom field for a contact](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/)
- [Add CiviCRM field on webform](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/webform/)

HTH

Pradeep